# Android MediaPlayer return Prepare failed.: status=0x1 on device but runs in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play an audio streaming from a remote `http` uri trough `MediaPlayer`.
The code seems to work fine in the emulator audio stream is played (but there's some noise over it) if I try to play on the device the `.prepare()` call fails throwing an IO exception. The message reports: `status=0x1` . The only articles related with this error I found where talking about reading/writing permissions over files and I think this's not the case, some other where related to wrong sequence of calls (.setDataSource, .prepare(), .start()) neither this should be my problem.

This's the code I'm using:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final int REQUEST_INTERNET = 21;

    private ImageButton exit_button;
    private ImageButton stop_button;
    private ImageButton play_button;

    private MediaPlayer media_player;

    private String uri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        boolean _skip_init = false;

        int check_internet = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.INTERNET);

        if (check_internet != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i(getClass().getName(), "asking for internet access permission");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                    REQUEST_INTERNET);

            _skip_init = true;
        }

        getSettings(this); // set uri 

        exit_button = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        play_button = findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        stop_button = findViewById(R.id.stop_button);

        exit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO: start play
                if(media_player!=null) {
                    media_player.start();
                    disablePlay();
                }
            }
        });

        stop_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO: stop play
                if(media_player!=null){
                    media_player.stop();
                    media_player.reset();
                    initStreaming(uri);
                    enablePlay();
                }
            }
        });

        play_button.setEnabled(false);
        stop_button.setEnabled(false);
        play_button.setAlpha(0.5f);
        stop_button.setAlpha(0.5f);

        if(!_skip_init) {
            initMediaPlayer(this);
            initStreaming(uri);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if ((requestCode == REQUEST_INTERNET) && (grantResults.length > 0)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                if ((grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    Log.i(getClass().getName(), permissions[i] + " permission granted");

                    if (Manifest.permission.INTERNET.equals(permissions[i])) {
                        initMediaPlayer(this);
                        initStreaming(uri);
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private void initMediaPlayer(@NonNull final Context context) {
        media_player = new MediaPlayer();
        media_player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        media_player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "onPreparedListener");
                play_button.setEnabled(true);
                play_button.setAlpha(1f);
            }
        });

        media_player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "onCompletionListener");
                Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.streaming_completed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initStreaming(@NonNull final String uri) {
        new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                       media_player.setDataSource(uri);
                       media_player.prepareAsync();
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                       Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
           }
       ).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //TODO: stop and free resources?
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "onDestroy");

        if(media_player!=null && media_player.isPlaying())
            media_player.stop();

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void enablePlay() {
        play_button.setEnabled(true);
        stop_button.setEnabled(false);
        play_button.setAlpha(1f);
        stop_button.setAlpha(0.5f);
    }

    private void disablePlay() {
        play_button.setEnabled(false);
        stop_button.setEnabled(true);
        play_button.setAlpha(0.5f);
        stop_button.setAlpha(1f);
    }
}
```

Where's the error? Is possible to fix it?

Why the emulator is able to run it without errors?

--- UPDATE ---

same error using `.prepareAsync()`

--- UPDATE ---

On the very same hardware configuration (Samsung Galaxy S9 stock), where the application worked with the simple fix when uploaded trough `adb` over usb link once the app is signed in release variant it stopped working and I got again the same error code reported above.
On different hardware like Huawei P30 it works (installed as a signed release .apk).
Can this depend on a firewall rule?

Comment: There's no need in asking internet permission. Declaring it in the manifest is enough. Of course, that's not the reason for your issue

Comment: yes I know but I tried it to see if it was a possible error cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem is fixed by this entry:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` file (*application* section).

-- UPDATE --

Actually the problem was given by some abnormal firewall rules that rejects connections from the same host after a give number of consecutive access.

Comment: of course I cannot understand why it was running trough emulators while it wasn't on real hardware....